# Pandas Groupby multiple columns (Timeseries, String Column) fails

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a TimeSeries data that I am trying to group by Month and the followed by the the type of service, so basically group on multiple columns.

I can get each groupby to work independetly (see both cases below).  However, when I try to group both together in it fails with the following exception (below)

First groupby is just on the 'service' column:

```
df_service =df_mem[['service','amount']].groupby('service').agg(['sum','count'])


                                                   sum count
service                                                     
10-Class Pack - $170+HST                       1728.90     9
646 Blue T-shirt (stars)                         25.00     1
646 Foundations + 12 classes $210+HST           237.30     1
646 Foundations + 8 Classes - $159+HST          876.38     5
646 Klawkov Tee, Wonder Woman Tee, 2 Drop-Ins    96.05     1
Bronze (8/mth)                                 1830.60    12
Bronze (8/mth) $135+HST                        1121.07    10
Clothing - Sweatpants XL, Grey Hoodie L          94.27     2
Drop-In $20+HST                                 158.20     7
Gold (Unlimited) - $185+HST                    1604.56    19
Leather lifting straps                           25.00     1
Men's Dimas Tee, Large                           28.25     1
Open Gym                                        220.35     3
Open Gym - $65+HST                               83.07     3
Red 646 Raglan, Large                            33.90     1
Silver                                         2237.40    12
Silver (12/mth) $165+HST                       1294.28    13
Test                                              2.00     2
Thumb Tape                                        6.25     1
Unlimited Gold                                 6898.65    33
Women's Fleece Pants                             48.59     1
Wonder Woman muscle tank (2) +HST                56.50     1
```

Second groupby is on TimeSeries Index (with frequency = Month):

```
df_montly_service = df_mem[['service','amount']].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).agg(['sum','count'])
             amount      
                sum count
date                     
2017-03-31     2.00     2
2017-04-30  3053.68    38
2017-05-31  4854.03    34
2017-06-30  5650.85    39
2017-07-31  5227.17    29
```

When I combine both together it fails:

```
df_montly_service = df_mem.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'),'service']).agg(['sum','count'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Karunyan/PycharmProjects/646W/import_data.py", line 24, in <module>
    df_montly_service = df_mem.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'),'service']).agg(['sum','count'])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3991, in groupby
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1511, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 370, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2484, in _get_grouper
    if not isinstance(gpr, Grouping) else gpr
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2262, in __init__
    grouper = self.grouper._get_binner_for_grouping(self.obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.py", line 1102, in _get_binner_for_grouping
    grouper = grouper.take(indexer)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.py", line 379, in take
    na_value=tslib.iNaT)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1539, in _assert_take_fillable
    taken = values.take(indices)
IndexError: index 142 is out of bounds for size 142




df_mem.head(15)

                              member                   service                       option       method  amount  ccy
date                                                                                                                 
2017-07-01 20:18:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 19:07:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 18:50:00  Names_coded_out            Bronze (8/mth)         subscription payment  credit card  152.55  cad
2017-07-01 18:33:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 18:15:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 18:14:00  Names_coded_out            Bronze (8/mth)         subscription payment  credit card  152.55  cad
2017-07-01 16:50:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 16:23:00  Names_coded_out                  Open Gym  subscription payment failed  credit card   73.45  cad
2017-07-01 16:09:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 15:22:00  Names_coded_out  Silver (12/mth) $165+HST         subscription prorate  credit card  179.00  cad
2017-07-01 15:20:00  Names_coded_out                    Silver         subscription payment  credit card  186.45  cad
2017-07-01 14:36:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 14:14:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
2017-07-01 14:06:00  Names_coded_out                    Silver         subscription payment  credit card  186.45  cad
2017-07-01 13:57:00  Names_coded_out            Unlimited Gold         subscription payment  credit card  209.05  cad
```

Comment: Can you post `df_mem.head()`?

Comment: updated to include dataframe

Comment: @Karun, can't reproduce that error using posted data set - everything is working... What is your Pandas version?

Comment: pandas v.0.19.2    looks like I can upgrade to 0.20.3. I'll try that. Fingers crossed

Comment: I could not reproduce with 0.19.2.

Comment: SOLVED: Found the problem on of the index as NaT, hence why it was failing. I dropped the NaT index item and the groupby on both timeseries and multiple column worked.